# PHP: scan all directories/folders for instances of PHP "error_log" files

Tags: php, error-handling

What would be an efficient way to have PHP scan all directories for instances of "error_log" files (generated PHP error log files) and save their location/paths to an array?

The point is to be aware of errors that aren't being logged to a database and bypassing the need to manually go through each directory via FTP. The time saved would be better used to correcting errors one was previously unaware of.

Comment: Why not change the [`error_log`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) setting to have all errors written to a single file?

Comment: @grossvogel How could we do that please? Thanks for the idea!

Comment: The best place to change this setting would be in your [php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) or in your web server's [configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php). If that's not possible, you can use the php function [`ini_set`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) to set it at runtime. (The issue with the runtime setting is that it won't work for errors that happen before the `ini_set` call.)

Comment: @grossvogel Great idea, I've made a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501511/php-merge-all-error-log-files-in-to-a-single-file