# PHP: merge all error_log files in to a single file

Tags: php, error-handling

Is it possible to edit the php.ini file (or anything else) and have all the *php_log* files be merged in to a single php_log file instead of one per directory?

Clarification for those who don't actually read: scanning a directory for a file type and merging files are two VERY separate actions with very different answers. Apparently the dup reporters NEVER asked two questions about a topic ever. >__>

Comment: "one per directory"? What are you taking about?

Comment: @Baba This is blatantly not a duplicate as merging and scanning are different contexts.

Comment: You need to scan before you merge .. one is dependent on the other .. you can easily make it 1 question  .. why 2 ?

Comment: @arkascha PHP logs errors in a file called error_log IN the directory where the error occurred. It would be more constructive to have a single combined error log.

Comment: @Baba Still completely different contexts and blatantly different if you read each question separately without rushing. Please stop chatting this question up so I can try the answers provided by one_trick_pony.

Comment: Sorry, but I have never seen such a configuration / installation... Actually what does "where the error occurs" mean? The current working directory? Or where a script has been started? What a weired setup... My logs are certainly all kept in a single directory...

Comment: @arkascha Apparently if error log is not an explicitly defined path to a file to be merged then it creates a separate file PER directory, 500 dirs/errors in each then 500 "error_log" files generated. The other question allows me to do a one-time clean-up and do possible rescans in the future (my current host keeps hosing my php.ini file and needs to be slapped in to this century).

Comment: May I suggest you change your host then?

Comment: @arkascha Yeah that's been in the works for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `error_log` directive from the [php.ini](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=php.ini-production;hb=HEAD#l582) file.

The value must be an absolute path to the file where you wish the errors to be logged. If it's relative, PHP will create that file in the directory where the script exists (the one in which the error came up). That's probably the reason why you have error_logs in each directory :)

As a side node, if you don't have access to the configuration file, it's [possible to change this setting at runtime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php). Something like `ini_set('error_log', __DIR__ . '/errors');` in your index.php script

Comment: I'll try this out in a minute or two, sounds like the answer though!

Comment: Does this require an Apache restart? I generally don't have tons of errors. This is pretty much the way my XAMPP php.ini file was configured (though win/*nix difference in paths).

Comment: If you're using XAMPP, I think you need to restart all services yes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all the "error reports" in one file (txt for example).
Create a txt file and write there the result of an error handler along with other info like date etc.
That way, every time that an error occurs the msg will be written in this unique file.